# PowerShell Converto-html format style

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to output powershell result into html file by using code below:

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:white;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:white}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:white}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

Get-item c:\work | select-object Name,Lastwritetime,@{label="Size" ; expression={[math]::round(((Get-childitem -force "c:\work" -recurse | measure-object length -sum).sum/1Gb),1)}}
get-childitem .....| Convertto-html -head $a | Out-File -append C:\temp\backup.htm
....
....
```

The result of html file looks like this:

[image]

So my question is:

How to have only one `Name LastTime Size` row on top and how to fix the length of the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you use ConvertTo-Html, you are creating a new table. That's why the widths are not consistent.

Get all of your results for the table into a single variable, then convert it to html once. That will create a single html table, with one header, and consistent widths.

Comment: thanks for the hint, there will be over 50 lines of `get-childitem`, how to get em all into a single variable? or it is better to use array? Sorry I dont have too much experience in powershell

Comment: Why do you need so many separate Get-ChildItem lines? Show a few of them - there is likely a way to get everything you need in a simpler way.

Comment: If you really need the separate calls to Get-ChildItem you can do something like:
    $items = Get-ChildItem ...;
    $items += Get-ChildItem ...;
    $items += Get-ChildItem ...;

Comment: I updated my post with a `get-childitem` line. basically what I trying to do is very simple, get a folder name lasttime and size from a list of PCs. I was trying to use `foreach` looping through the pclist.txt file, but could not make it work lol... so I just use the simplest way to do it. btw, thanks for your hint, i chose array to made it work now. but i would like to hear a better way to do it if you dont mind.